# Is conversion between vectors defined behavior?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, language-lawyer, stdvector, undefined-behavior

In order to serialize components in my game, I need to be able to access the data in various vectors only given a pointer and a size for the vector.

I want to get the data() pointer from a vector if I have only a void * pointing to the vector. I am attempting to convert from `std::vector<T>` to `std::vector<char>` to get the data() pointer. I want to know if the following code is defined behavior and not going to act any different in different situations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> ints = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 };

    std::vector<char>* memory = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char>*>(&ints);
    int *intArray = reinterpret_cast<int *>(memory->data());

    std::cout << intArray[0] << intArray[1] << intArray[2] << intArray[3] << intArray[4] << std::endl; //01234 Works on gcc and vc++
    std::getchar();
}
```

This seems to work in this isolated case, but I don't know if it will give errors or undefined behavior inside the serialization code.

Comment: Why are you going through `std::vector<char>`? You don't know the original type?

Comment: @Mat The only thing known about the vector is the size of its data in bytes.

Comment: I toss this into the "Probably work, but violates Strict Aliasing, so the results are not guaranteed" bin. Is there any chance of templating this so you don't lose the type? In other words, your example may be too simple for anyone to point out all the potential problems.

Comment: Why not just `char* memory = reinterpret_cast<char*>(ints.data())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an aliasing violation:

```
std::vector<char>* memory = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char>*>(&ints);
int *intArray = reinterpret_cast<int *>(memory->data());
```

Per [basic.life], accessing `memory->data()` here has undefined behavior.

The way to get around this is to call `ints.data()` to obtain a `int*` pointer to the underlying contiguous array. Afterwards, you are allowed to cast it to `void*`, `char*`, or `unsigned char*` (or `std::byte*` in C++17).

From there you can cast back to `int*` to access the elements again.

Comment: Casting an `int*` to `char*`, then back to `int*` and *then* using it is not an aliasing violation.

Comment: @rustyx But that's not what happened here. We cast a `vector<int>*` to `vector<char>*` and **used it** without first casting back to `vector<int>*`. If the line had been `reinterpret_cast<int*>(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ints.data()))` then that would have been an `int* -> char* -> int*` cast sequence.

Comment: Huh? The *dynamic type* on the original array is `int[]` and remains so. It may be aliased with `char*`, but that doesn't magically change it to `char[]`.

Comment: @rustyx: Please re-read OPs code. They cast a `std::vector<int>*` to `std::vector<char>*`, and then call `std::vector<char>::data` through the resulting pointer. This is a strict aliasing violation and therefore UB. It doesn't matter that they *eventually* cast the pointer back to `int*`. the fact of the matter is that they performed indirection through the pointer. Refer to N4659 6.8: "Indirection through such a pointer is permitted but the resulting lvalue may only
be used in limited ways, as described below. The program has undefined behavior if..."

Comment: @rustyx: Are you still not convinced?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is UB.

With `reinterpret_cast<std::vector<char>*>(&ints)`, you are casting a vector-object to another vector object of different (and actually incompatible) type. Yet you do not dereference the resulting pointer, and - as both vector objects will very likely have the same aliasing restrictions - the cast will be OK. Cf, for example, [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.reinterpret.cast#7) online C++ draft). Note that a vector does not store the data types "in place" but will hold a pointer to the values.

> **5.2.10 Reinterpret cast**
>
> (7) An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of
>   a different type.70 When a prvalue v of type “pointer to T1” is
>   converted to the type “pointer to cv T2”, the result is static_cast(static_cast(v)) if both T1 and T2 are standard-layout
>   types ([basic.types]) and the alignment requirements of T2 are no
>   stricter than those of T1, or if either type is void. Converting a
>   prvalue of type “pointer to T1” to the type “pointer to T2” (where T1
>   and T2 are object types and where the alignment requirements of T2 are
>   no stricter than those of T1) and back to its original type yields the
>   original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer
>   conversion is unspecified.

So casting a vector object forth and back should work in a defined manner here.

Second, you cast a pointer that originally points (and is aliased to) `int` "back" to its original type `int`. So aliasing is obviously not violated.

I don't see any UB here (unless a vector-object had stricter aliasing rules than a vector-object, which is very likely not the case).

Comment: @AndyG: yes, it is. I oversaw that the vector-object is not casted back.

Comment: Looks like you can now :-)

Comment: @AndyG: and will in a view minutes :-)